# Is there any documentation available which helps in applying LDS to aura ui components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

It seems that LDS has lots of features but when you try to use that with Lightning components, it can not be used like for ui:radioInput where id in the for clause is requird. There you can not set id of for ui:radioInput it is auto generated.
There seems to be gap between LDS and lightning components. They should be played well together. I looked for documentation but didn't find any.

Is there any documentation which could help how to use lightning components along with the LDS stlyes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Winter 17 released something recently known as [lightning base components](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_base_lightning_components.htm?edition=&impact=) .These are supposed to bridge lot of gaps between SLDS and the lightning component framework .

While some of the components are in BETA still it has large set of components that are almost PROD ready .

If you are testing this inside an app use extends="SLDS" for aura:application

Take a look at [Lightning Input tag](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm) and type=radio

If your sandbox is upgraded to winter 17 then try below

```
 <lightning:input type="radio" name="Radio" 
label="Radio" value="" />
```

Also I have re documented since i found docs had some gaps in explaining .In case you are interested ,take a look [here](https://github.com/msrivastav13/Base-Lightning-Components/wiki/Lightning-Base-Components-Designer-Guide)

Comment: Thanks Mohith, this is great. I will go through your docs. This what exactly I was looking for.